# adding element with duplicate id 'FileULoader' FileUploader

Tags: javascript, file-upload, sapui5

```
createContent : function(oController) {

        var oFileUploader  = new sap.ui.commons.FileUploader({
            id: "FileULoader",
        //uploadUrl : "UploadFileServelet",   // URL to submit the form to
        name: "simpleUploader",          // name of the input type=file element within the form 
    //  uploadOnChange: true,           // immediately upload the file after selection
        buttonOnly: false,
        buttonText: "Upload"
        }).addStyleClass("downloadBtn");
        oFileUploader.attachUploadComplete(oController.doFileLoadComplete);  
    //var uploadBtn=new sap.ui.commons.buttons{this.creatId("upLoadFile"),}



    var oMatrix = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout({
        layoutFixed : true,
        width : '400px',
        columns : 1 });

    var text = new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text:"Confirm that the data will be wiped out once you upload new data file."});

    oMatrix.createRow(oFileUploader);
    oMatrix.createRow(text);

    var oDialog = new sap.ui.commons.Dialog({
        title:"FileUpload",
        resizable:false,
        modal:true,
        showCloseButton:true,
        contentBorderDesign:"Box",
        content:[
                 oMatrix   
        ],
        buttons:[
            new sap.ui.commons.Button({text:"Confirm", tooltip:"Confirm",press:function(e){oController.doFileUpload();oDialog.close();}}),
            new sap.ui.commons.Button({text:"Cancel", tooltip:"Cancle",press:function(e){oDialog.close();}}),
        ]
    });
    return oDialog;
```

i  used  in  two views . when i  call the fileUploader  the error turns  out。
i have to  use  the id  to identify the fileloder controller. to get the input file information .

update:

```
_uploadCourse:function(){
    if (!this.dialogUploadFile) {
        this.dialogUploadFile = sap.ui.jsfragment("courseUP",
                "adminView.dialogUploadFile", this);
    }
    this.dialogUploadFile.open();
},
_uploadCourse : function() {

                    if (!this.dialogUploadFile) {
                        this.dialogUploadFile = sap.ui.jsfragment("certiUploadFile",
                                "adminView.dialogUploadFile", this);
                    }
                    this.dialogUploadFile.open();
                },
```

this  is how i use the fragment. but is  still go wrong with thew same error;
@Allen Zhang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned you used the code in two views. You can't create a dialog twice with the same id of Fileupload control. Use different id for different views.

Updated：

Define id for your fragment usage:

```
<core:Fragment id="myFrag" fragmentName='my.frag' type='JS' />
```

Define fileupload id by calling **createId**:

```
var oFileUploader  = new sap.ui.commons.FileUploader({
        id: this.createId("FileULoader"),
    //uploadUrl : "UploadFileServelet",   // URL to submit the form to
    name: "simpleUploader",     // name of the input type=file element within the form 
//  uploadOnChange: true,           // immediately upload the file after selection
    buttonOnly: false,
    buttonText: "Upload"
    }).addStyleClass("downloadBtn");
```

Also see my answers about [fragment usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301081/adding-element-with-duplicate-id) and [get control inside fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379476/sap-ui-5-how-i-can-set-fragment).

Comment: i try this, but it didn't work. so i  creat another fragments to do it.   i  wonder   is there any method to get the control not by id. but by type or  something else?

Comment: could you please elaborate your requirement? The same fragment is used by multiple views and you need to get the uploader control?

Comment: but when it  has  an id. the dupiulicate id error exit. so my question is : is there anyway to get an controller  that it has no id?  BTW: is there any solution to  make the fragments to Singleton？ thanks  in advance.

Comment: Hi, give fragment an id when you use and let the uploader id be this.createId("FileULoader"), this method will generate fragment id prefixed id for uploader.

Comment: Unfortunately the question was put on hold so I can´t post an answer but to use the fragment as a singleton you can do it the same way as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24278751/1969374).

Comment: hi, you need to maintain two different instances of dialog fragment.See this example i did in JSbin http://jsbin.com/kahaxo/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Is an option that you do not use id for the file uploader control, and do it like this?

```
createContent : function(oController) {
    this.oFileUploader = new sap.ui.commons.FileUploader({
```

To access it, you do

```
view.oFileUploader
```

where view is the javascript handle of one of your two views.

-D