# "setInitialFocusId" error after _oDialog.destroy()

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I get the error following error when trying to open a Dialog fragment a second time after calling `this._oDialog.destroy()`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setInitialFocusId' of null

My problem is like the problem stated here: [How to clear dialog/xmlfragment content after close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484467/how-to-clear-dialog-xmlfragment-content-after-close) However, the solution apparently just seems to be "Don't use the property setInitialFocus", which I do not use anywhere in my code.

### Controller

```
openDialog: function() {
  if (!this._oDialog) {
    this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("myFragmentPath", this);
    this.getView().addDependent(this._oDialog);
  }
  this._oDialog.open();
},

onExit: function () {
  if (this._oDialog) {
    this._oDialog.destroy();
  }
},

afterClose: function () {
  if (this._oDialog) {
    this._oDialog.destroy();
  }
},

handleClose: function (oEvent) {
  this._oDialog.close();
}
```

### Dialog Fragment

```xml
<Dialog xmlns="sap.m" afterClose=".afterClose">
  <!-- ... -->
</Dialog>
```

### Main XML View

```xml
<Button press=".openDialog" />
```

---

**Additional info:**

- The error message occurs in the Controller line when `this._oDialog.open();` is called.
- I am using the sap library version 1.60.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
if (this._oDialog) {
  this._oDialog.destroy();
  this._oDialog = null; // make it falsy so that it can be created next time
}
```

After close, the dialog is destroyed in your code. **However,** the `this._oDialog` is still there.

Since `this._oDialog` is not a falsy value but just a *destroyed* dialog instance, there is no new Dialog created in `openDialog()` second time. Hence **you're trying to open a destroyed dialog.**

When the dialog is destroyed, its internal `oPopup` is [set to null](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/ccfcdc2fd818175379fedfde2a1dc807e42a0096/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Dialog.js#L566-L623), which explains the error message.

---

### ⚠️ Note

1. There is usually **no need to destroy the dialog** after closing. When the view gets destroyed, the dialog will be destroyed automatically since the fragment is dependent to the view. If the intention was to reset data values, try [unbinding properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56988598/5846045) instead of destroying and recreating the entire fragment every time which is quite costly.
2. Since UI5 1.56, the factory function **`sap.ui.xmlfragment` is deprecated** because it fetches the fragment via sync XHR (blocking the main thread). Use one of the [new asynchronous APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64662830/5846045).
3. A simpler option is to **add the fragment declaratively** in your view definition with `<core:Fragment fragmentName="..." type="XML" />` to the `<dependents>` aggregation of a certain control. [Like in this sample](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.ActionSheet/sample/sap.m.sample.ActionSheet/code).