# Same fragment used in different controllers - Duplicate ID error on opening

Tags: sapui5

I have an XML fragment which I have used in 2 different views. When I click on a table row for item *A* -  view *A* opens and if I click on "Save" on that page - Fragment opens. Depending upon the action the user did on the Fragment (it has 2 buttons - Yes/ Cancel), next step happens but I close the fragment at the end of the process. If I click on Item *B* in the table - view *B* opens. If I click on "Save" on this page, expectation is the same fragment should open. But instead I get a **duplicate ID error**.

One observation: if I use a different Fragment (similar in design) in both, the controllers issue is resolved. Everything works fine. But if same, fragment error.
Not sure why close if not working correctly. Tried `destroy()` but then it gave me `setInititalFocus()` undefined something like that error.

Controller A.js ***Similar code is in ControllerB.js***

```js
onManageConfirmation: function(oEvent) {
  var ccModelObj = {
    "headerText": "Hello",
    "operation": "deleteItem"
  };
  if (!this.ABC) {
    var ccModel = new JSONModel(); // required "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
      this.ABC= sap.ui.xmlfragment("...fragments.commons.ManageConfirmation", this);
    this.getView().addDependent(this.ABC);
    this.ABC.setModel(ccModel);
  }
  this.ABC.getModel().setData(ccModelObj);
  this.ABC.open();
},

onYes: function(oEvent) {
  this.ABC.close();
},

onCancel: function(oEvent) {
// in fragment also added onClose property and calling this method only
  this.ABC.close();
},
```

Comment: About _"Tried destroy() but then it gave me setInititalFocus()"_, take a look at [“setInitialFocusId” error after _oDialog.destroy()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54214764/5846045)

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess here, but your *this* is referencing two different things in your controllers.

When your in controller A everything works like a charm but then you load controller B and the check for *this.ABC* returns false and your code tries to load a fragment that is already at the DOM hence the duplicate Id error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your fragment.xml if you have used any ids inside of it ? If yes you must ensure to destroy the fragment before opening it again.